# Removing rows using unique(data.table) or distinct (dplyr) and partial gsub

Tags: r, data.table, unique, distinct, gsub

I have a dataset lets say DT1 to it. DT1 has 2 columns, City and Places. I'll match DT1 with another dataset (DT2) to fill the missing City values. But as you can see some places are in different cities with same names. I want to remove this places and match rest of them with DT2. Here is my DT1.

```r
DT1 <- data.table::data.table(city = c("XXX", "XXX", "YYY","ZZZ"),
 places= c("apple","orange","apple","pineapple"))

#> City     BirthPlace
#> XXX      apple
#> XXX      orange
#> YYY      apple
#> ZZZ      pineapple
```

When I use unique or distinct it keeps 1 of the apples, and that causes problems in DT2 because even if my **apple** place belongs to YYY it pastes XXX to city column in DT2.

here is an example of DT2

```r
DT2 <- data.table::data.table(zipcode = c("00001","00002","00003","00004"),
                  birthplace= c("apple","orange","pineapple","grapes")

#> ZipCode  BirthPlace
#> 00001      apple
#> 00002      orange
#> 00003      pineapple
#> 00004      grapes
```

As you can see I have an **apple** place in DT2. I dont know location of it, is it in city XXX or in YYY. Thats why I need to remove all **apple** rows in DT1 but unique or distincts functions doesnt allow me as far as I can see they always keep first row.

this is what I want to achieve

```r
DT3 <- data.table::data.table(city = c("XXX","ZZZ"),
                  birthplace= c("orange","grapes"),
                  zipcode = c("00002","00004")
#>  City BirthPlace ZipCode
#>   XXX    orange  00002
#>   ZZZ    grapes  00004
```

besides that some of the birthplace values includes punctuation such as **apple st.** I tried to split this and leave apple alone with   `gsub("^(st.)*$","",dt2$birthplace)` but it also didnt work any suggestions about this guys?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An option with `data.table`

```
library(data.table)
DT1[, if(.N == 1) .SD, places][DT2, on = .(places = birthplace), nomatch = 0]
```

Answer (score 1):

Using `dplyr` you can remove all "apples" by counting all occurances in your column `places`:

```r
DT1 %>%
  group_by(places) %>%
  filter(n() == 1)
```

This gives you

```
# A tibble: 2 x 2
# Groups:   places [2]
  city  places   
  <chr> <chr>    
1 XXX   orange   
2 ZZZ   pineapple
```

Merging both Data.Tables

```r
merge(DT1, DT2, by.x="places", by.y="birthplace")
```

yields

```r
     places city zipcode
1    orange  XXX   00002
2 pineapple  ZZZ   00003
```

Comment: Ty for your answer. I also find another way to solve, in case people needs it 

```DT1[!(duplicated(DT1$places) | duplicated(DT1$places, fromLast = TRUE)), ]``` 

still couldnt solve the partial match problem tho. Do you have any suggestion for that?